# Secure WebSocket over NGINX

Tags: angularjs, node.js, nginx, https, websocket

I'm stuck with Secure Websocket over nginx. I recently use nginx to propose a secure connection. But the Websocket implementation, that worked with HTTP protocol now failed with HTTPS.

**Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502**

Here is the previous configuration with changes commented :

**BACK**

```
var app = require('../app');
var http = require('http');
var ws = require('nodejs-websocket');
var port = normalizePort('8000');
app.set('port', port);
var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port);

var serv = ws.createServer(function (connection) {
var serv = ws.createServer({ 'secure' : true }, function (connection) { //with HTTPS
  connection.on('text', function (msg) {
    connection.sendText(msg)
  })
}).listen(server)
```

**FRONT**

```
var dataStream = $websocket('ws://address/ws');
var dataStream = $websocket('wss://address/ws'); //with HTTPS
```

**NGINX Configuration**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name slnxdakitg01.ptx.fr.sopra;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri; #without ssl, I just put location at this place
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    (... ssl stuff ...)

    location /ws {
        proxy_pass              http://address:8000;
        proxy_http_version      1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header        Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass      $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

I already consulted topics dealing with NGINX config without results...

Comment: What do the logs tell you? Does it get to the backend and error out there? Or is it in nginx?

Comment: @ShawnC. the error occured in nginx side

By the way, this small change fix my problem. WebSocket works over nginx. 
**proxy_set_header        Upgrade websocket;**